Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function
as title writed. i got this error in google map api 3.59.1.
for some reason, i use leaflet + googleMutant to drive google map api.
since 2024/11/21 the 3.59 new one was pernounced, i try to change to new google map api version 3.59, but i got this error message. and map don`t work, can not be appeared.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function

error location:
map.js -> owa(...b)
but in version 3.58, it works normally.
check the new features.

This is a known issue that was reported in Google's Issue Tracker. You can view and star the issue to get updates on it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/382422288

You need update googleMutant latest
https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/dist/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js

I updated my googlemutant a couple of days ago and found that I get the error on some servers but not other. cant be sure I have the latest since no version no. in the comments, but seems likely. The gitlab repo doesnt have new commits

thx so much. the version of my googlemutant is 0.8.0. when i up-grade it to latest version 0.14.1, it can  resolve my problem.
